# Java: Как правильно синхронизировать потоки?

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, классы, синхронизация

Всем привет. У меня не получается синхронизировать потоки, из-за чего происходят траблы с консолью (по крайней мере, я так думаю, что всё дело в синхронизации потоков) — она выводит:

> Содержимое файла: 6 8 6 9 7 8 8 6 0 6 2 9 8 0 4 7 3 0 5 4

> Количество нечётных чисел: 6

> Количество чётных чисел:   11

> **Нечётные числа:  Чётные числа:** 9 7 9 7 3 5

> 6 8 6 8 8 6 6 2 8 4 4

Хотя должна выводить что-то вроде этого:

> Содержимое файла: 1 9 4 5 0 4 9 8 7 3 3 1 5 4 7 4 4 3 9 8

> Количество чётных чисел:   7

> Чётные числа:  4 4 8 4 4 4 8

> Количество нечётных чисел: 12

> Нечётные числа:    1 9 5 9 7 3 3 1 5 7 3 9

Один поток ищет чётные числа, а второй — нечётные.
Есть также и третий поток, который заполняет массив случайными числами, после чего, остальные два потока стартуют. Пример содержимого текстовика: *1 9 4 5 0 4 9 8 7 3 3 1 5 4 7 4 4 3 9 8*.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    static int My_Array[]; static String path1; static String file_name1;
    static void printResult1(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        System.out.print("Чётные числа:\t");
        for (String number : numbers) { if (Integer.parseInt(number) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(number) % 2 == 0) { System.out.print(number + " "); } }
    }
    static void printResult2(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        System.out.print("Нечётные числа:\t");
        for (String number : numbers) { if (Integer.parseInt(number) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(number) % 2 != 0) { System.out.print(number + " "); } }
    }

    static class My_random_numbers_Thread extends Thread
    {
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            // Сгенерировать массив из 20и рандомных чисел диапазоном 0-10
            My_Array = new int[20]; for (int i = 0; i < My_Array.length; i++) { My_Array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*11); }

            // Перезаписать данные файла и записать в файл массив рандомных чисел
            int new_data[] = My_Array;
            BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
            try { outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_name1)); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            for (int i = 0; i < new_data.length; i++)
            {
                try { outputWriter.write(new_data[i] + " "); }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
            try { outputWriter.flush(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { outputWriter.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println("Файл перезаписан и прочитан!");
        }
    }

    static class My_search_for_even_numbers_Thread extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Поиск чётных чисел
            int count1 = 0;
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path1)))
            { while (sc.hasNextInt()) { int i = sc.nextInt(); if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0) { count1++; } } }
            catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println("Количество чётных чисел:\t" + count1);
            File file = new File(path1);
            try { printResult1(file);System.out.println(); }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
    }

    static class My_search_for_odd_numbers_Thread extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Поиск нечётных чисел
            int count2 = 0;
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path1)))
            { while (sc.hasNextInt()) { int i = sc.nextInt(); if (i % 2 != 0 && i != 0) { count2++; } } }
            catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println("Количество нечётных чисел:\t" + count2);
            File file = new File(path1);
            try { printResult2(file);System.out.println(); }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Указать путь+файл(-.txt) и проверить на предмет наличия файла
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введи путь: "); /*C:/Users/Test_User/IdeaProjects/Test_Console1/Test_text.txt*/
        path1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        file_name1 = path1;
        File file1 = new File(file_name1); if (file1.exists()) { System.out.println("Файл есть!"); } else { System.out.println("Файла нет!"); }

        // Thread: Сгенерировать рандомные числа
        new My_random_numbers_Thread().start();
        Thread.sleep(500);

        // Прочитать и вывести данные из файла
        try(FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file_name1))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fis1.available()];
            fis1.read(buffer);
            String file_data1 = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println("\nСодержимое файла: " + file_data1);
            int i = -1;
            while ((i=fis1.read()) != -1) { System.out.print((char)i); }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
        Thread.sleep(500);

        // Thread: Чётные числа
        new My_search_for_even_numbers_Thread().start();
        // Thread: Нечётные числа
        new My_search_for_odd_numbers_Thread().start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потоков три, а консоль одна, поток пытаются писать в консоль и возникает race condition.

Comment: А как это пофиксить? Я ранее дел с этим не имел просто...

Comment: Что пофиксить? Разные потоки не могут писать консоль одновременно. Если вы будете останавливать поток, потому, что вам надо записать в консоль, то нет смысла в многопоточности. Потоки будут тормозить друг друга пока не запишут в консоль. Потом оба потока завершат работу одновременно, независимо от того, что они связаны. Консоль это сложный объект, который обновляется если поступает событие, что надо обновить экран. Событие попадает в очередь и не всегда блокирует ввод перед обновлением.

Comment: Останавливал, потому что экспериментировал и искал решение проблемы. Но пришёл к выводу, что нужно использовать синхронность. Вот только как её корректно и правильно оформить?

Comment: тут нечего выполнять асинхронно, вместо потоков просто переделай их в функции и вызови последовательно по одной

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, зачем вам нужно тут использовать многопоточность. Если это учебный пример, который имитирует ситуацию, когда несколько потоков работают и пишут в поток вывода и нужно чтоб вывод не перемешивался, то тогда это понятно и можно ответить. Если же причина другая, то нужно ее указать, так как решение, вполне возможно, будет в том, чтоб изменить структуру кода. Одним словом напишите, зачем вам это нужно.

Comment: Я так вот сделал: https://github.com/PavelIks/DZPotoki/blob/master/src/com/company/Main.java

Comment: Строки: 77-206.

Comment: Да, это такой таск, его условия.

Comment: В условии задачи по ссылке нет ничего про то, что потоки должны что-то выводить в System.out. Как раз там есть условие, что они возвращают значения в `main` и уже `main` значения отображает: `Полученный массив, сумма и среднеарифметическое возвращаются в метод main, где должны быть отображены.` При такой постановке описанной в этом вопросе проблемы в принципе не будет.

Comment: Строки: 77-207. В таске требовались простые числа и факториал каждого числа в потоке. Но я пока обошёлся чётными-нечётными числами.

**Пользователь с клавиатуры вводит путь к файлу. После
чего запускаются три потока. Первый поток заполняет
файл случайными числами. Два других потока ожидают
заполнения. Когда файл заполнен оба потока стартуют.
Первый поток находит все простые числа, второй поток
факториал каждого числа в файле. Результаты поиска
каждый поток должен записать в новый файл. В методе
main необходимо отобразить статистику выполненных
операций.**